# Ionic/Angular Capacitor plugin & firebase FB auth : FacebookLogin does not have web implementation error

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, facebook-authentication, capacitor

Here is my `"sign in"` function that works perfectly on `Android` and allows me to use `Facebook` `auth` in `myapp` :

```
  async signIn(): Promise<void> {
    const FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS = ['public_profile', 'email'];

    const result = await Plugins.FacebookLogin.login({ permissions: FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS });
    if (result && result.accessToken) {
      let user = { token: result.accessToken.token, userId: result.accessToken.userId }
      let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
        queryParams: {
          userinfo: JSON.stringify(user)
        }
      };
      this.router.navigate(["/feed"], navigationExtras);
    }
  }
```

I would like to test my app like I used to do on my browser but I got this error:
**Error:**

> ```
> core.js:4197 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FacebookLogin does not have web implementation.
> at resolvePromise (VM1677 polyfills.js:3904)
> at VM1677 polyfills.js:3811
> at rejected (VM1678 vendor.js:113087)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (VM1677 polyfills.js:3470)
> at Object.onInvoke (VM1678 vendor.js:62348)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (VM1677 polyfills.js:3469)
> at Zone.run (VM1677 polyfills.js:3229)
> at VM1677 polyfills.js:3963
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (VM1677 polyfills.js:3505)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (VM1678 vendor.js:62336)
> ```

I tried to register my capacitor plugin using

```
import { registerWebPlugin } from '@capacitor/core';

registerWebPlugin(FacebookLogin);
```

But this is not working at all and this is the only solution I found via google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon at [Devdactic.com](https://devdactic.com/) put together a great tutorial about [Ionic Facebook Login with Capacitor](https://devdactic.com/ionic-facebook-login-capacitor/). There are a few things that need to be setup to get the web implementation to work properly.

1. Load the Facebook SDK
2. Register the Facebook web plugin with Capacitor
3. Setup a switch to determine which version of the Facebook login to use based on the platform the app is running on.

In `index.html` add in JavaScript to initialize the Facebook SDK. Add this script tag after the body tag

```html
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
      appId: '#YOUR_APP_ID_HERE#',
      cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
      version: 'v5.0' // use graph api current version
    });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Next (step 2 & 3) register the FacebookLogin as a Web Plugin to Capacitor and setup the switch

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FacebookLoginPlugin } from '@capacitor-community/facebook-login';
import { Plugins, registerWebPlugin } from '@capacitor/core';
import { isPlatform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { FacebookLogin } from '@capacitor-community/facebook-login';
registerWebPlugin(FacebookLogin);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage {
  fbLogin: FacebookLoginPlugin;
  user = null;
  token = null;
 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.setupFbLogin();
  }
 
  async setupFbLogin() {
    if (isPlatform('desktop')) {
      this.fbLogin = FacebookLogin;
    } else {
      // Use the native implementation inside a real app!
      const { FacebookLogin } = Plugins;
      this.fbLogin = FacebookLogin;
    } 
  }
 
  async login() {
    const FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS = ['email', 'user_birthday'];
    const result = await this.fbLogin.login({ permissions: FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS });
 
    if (result.accessToken && result.accessToken.userId) {
      this.token = result.accessToken;
      this.loadUserData();
    } else if (result.accessToken && !result.accessToken.userId) {
      // Web only gets the token but not the user ID
      // Directly call get token to retrieve it now
      this.getCurrentToken();
    } else {
      // Login failed
    }
  }
 
  async getCurrentToken() {    
    const result = await this.fbLogin.getCurrentAccessToken();
 
    if (result.accessToken) {
      this.token = result.accessToken;
      this.loadUserData();
    } else {
      // Not logged in.
    }
  }
 
  async loadUserData() {
    const url = `https://graph.facebook.com/${this.token.userId}?fields=id,name,picture.width(720),birthday,email&access_token=${this.token.token}`;
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(res => {
      this.user = res;
    });
  }
 
  async logout() {
    await this.fbLogin.logout();
    this.user = null;
    this.token = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking up for answers ! Well, weirdly with my app this solution doesn't work. This is so confusing because this is legit the only solution found on internet regarding this problem :'(

Comment: Sorry, there was more to the web implementation than I realized. I updated my answer. Hopefully this will get you going. I do have a working example if you need it.

Comment: Thanks you so much !! I'm actually trying it, I'll get back to you when it will done. Thanks again for taking your time for me

Comment: This code is so different from mine that I don't what I should add and what I should remove. import { FacebookLogin } from '@capacitor-community/facebook-login;' ->  this cant be resolved, apparently

Comment: npm i @capacitor-community/facebook-login will add the package. I understand it might be unrealistic to completely refactor your code. I guess the key takeaway would be that the capacitor plugin needs a bit of help to function similarly on the web as it does on Android.